# Use Blender script in other applications

Tags: scripting

I have written a simple script that allows me to import a DEM with .asc format into Blender. Now I want to study the waterflows of that portion of terrain. How can I do it? Can I write a different application (like in C#/Java) and use  the script from that application to show me a picture of the 3d model?

Or can it be done inside Blender?

Comment: please can you add more details?? like a example with images?

Comment: It isn't really very clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would continue scripting in Blender. It has a full Python 3 installation so there is nothing preventing you from writing a very complicated program inside it. Python is actually perfect for these kinds of experimental projects.

Writing anything in C# or Java adds a lot of tedious boiler plate to your project AND it's not exactly clear how you would call Blender from an external application.